# Passing a variable function v->x to the int main function()

Tags: c, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I want to pass my v->x from my function "calculations_using_struct_values" to my "int main" function. What do I have to write inside the bracket for my "int main" function and my "int main" prototype to run the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void calculations_using_struct_values(struct test *v);
int main();

struct test
{
    int x,y,z;
    char *name;
};

void struct_values()
{
    test variable;

    variable.x=50;
    variable.y=100;
    variable.z=150;

    calculations_using_struct_values(&variable);
    return;
}

void calculations_using_struct_values(struct test *v)
{
    int a=5;
    v->x +=a;

    main();
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming a hosted environment: You shall not provide a declaration for `main` (which you do - does your compiler not warn already?). OTOH, `main` is undefined when you call it without prototype. This alone should give a strong hint it is a very bad idea to call `main` from another function in your code. Indeed it is deemed very bad practice -just don't! And don't use old-style declarators, but correct prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
void calculations_using_struct_values(struct test *v)
{
    int a=5;
    v->x +=a;

    main(); /* remove this call  */
}
```

do:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct_values(); /* call your function in main */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry I found it out. I was suppose to call struct test variable inside void struct_values. Anyway thanks